# How to update multiple elements for each data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

There are a lot of articles about how to update dom for each data. But what if I want to update multiple dom nodes for each data.

For example, for each data, generate div and span according to the number in the data.

```
[
  [1, 2],
  [2, 1],
]
```

I want to yield like

```
<div class="data">
  <div>1</div><span>2</span><span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="data">
  <div>2</div><div>2</div><span>1</span>
</div>
```

Should start with

```
const selection = d3.selectAll("div.data");
selection.exit().remove();
selection.enter().append("div").attr("class", "data").merge(selection); 
// Then I don't know how to add multiple dom according to the data value.
```

Comment: For each `<div class="data">` element you can acquire from `d3.selectAll("div.data"), you can get its respective children using [.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children). Then you can loop through those children. It just a loop within a loop.

Comment: Thanks Lonnie for looking at this. Your way probably work, but it's maybe best to do in a d3 way. Direct DOM operations are what we are trying to avoid by using d3.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your question's title ("*how to update multiple elements for each data"*) suggests that you want to *update* those elements, when in fact, by reading your actual question, you just want to create them (*enter*, in D3 lingo). Also, pay attention to the fact that you cannot use `data()` following `d3.selectAll()`.

That being said, there are several solutions. One of them is using `each()` for your outer divs, and then appending how many elements you want (divs or spans) by using `d3.range()`, which will create an array whose length is based on the number you pass to it. The actual content of that array is irrelevant, since the text in both divs and spans correspond to the numbers in the inner arrays.

Here is a simple example, pay attention to the colors for each element (outer divs, inner divs and spans):

```js
const body = d3.select("body");
const data = [
  [1, 2],
  [2, 1],
];
const dataDiv = body.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "data")
  .each(function(d) {
    d3.select(this).selectAll(null)
      .data(d3.range(d[0]))
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "innerDiv")
      .html(d[0]);
    d3.select(this).selectAll(null)
      .data(d3.range(d[1]))
      .enter()
      .append("span")
      .html(d[1]);
  })
```

```css
.data {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.innerDiv {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

span {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the generated HTML:

```
<div class="data">
  <div class="innerDiv">1</div><span>2</span><span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="data">
  <div class="innerDiv">2</div>
  <div class="innerDiv">2</div><span>1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
First of all, I do mean update. I have a merge() after the enter().append(). Also I have a exit().remove(). So that if it's not there, create it. If there update it.
Yeah, your code works pretty nice and as expected.
Since you are using 5.7. I can probably replace the enter to join and fit my purpose.

Answer (score -2):

d3 supports [nesting of selections](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).  The critical bit here is after binding data to the parent elements, call `parent.selectAll()` and then bind the data using a function instead of a variable, e.g., `parent.selectAll(child).data(d => d)`. d3 will automatically bind the nested arrays to each child element.  This is described in the [link](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/), which defines a `table` with nested `tr` and `td` elements:

> The data operator defines the array of data for each group. Here the data function is invoked once per row and successively passed each parent datum. Since the parent data is an array of arrays, the data function simply returns the inner array for each row of cells.

```js
 let data = [
   [1, 2],
   [2, 1],
 ]

 let selection =  d3.selectAll('div.data')
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("div")
 .attr("class", "data")

 selection
 .selectAll('span')
 .data(function(d) { 
  return  d;
 })
.enter()
.append('span')
.text(d => d)
```

```css
.data span {
 background: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 5px;
}

.data {
 background: yellow;
 margin: 10px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```